# query mongo : find count of array in all the documents of a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

query mongo to find the count of all cars array in each document of collection company

I am new to mongo, I

db.company.find() --> but then how do I select the arrays and that too for all of them

```
collection company : {

    {   
       "_id": "5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9",
        "company_location": "USA",
        "company_name": "gmc",
        "__v": 0,
        "cars": [{
                "_id": "5b8ed214044b2509466eca2e",
                "model": "TERRAIN",
                "year": 2013,
                "PriceInINR": 3851710,
                "trim": "SLE2 FWD",
                "engine": "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                "body": "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V FFV",
                "color": "Yellow",
                "transmission_type": "Manual",
                "dealer_id": "5b8e7ce7065fa50bee095072"
            },
              {------},
              {------}   
}
```

Comment: Try `db.company.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":null,"count":{"$sum":{"$size":"$cars"}}}})`

Comment: @Veeram hey can you help me with one more thing

Comment: Sure. What is it ?

Comment: @Veeram from last 5-6 hours I am trying to push data into mongo. and this is 12726 son objects. and it doesn't not work, like I don't know it works or not, so now finally when there is no way, I have break up 1400 json object into 7 .json files with each containing 200 objects. and now it works atleast.  so I am proceeding to build other things. --> which is the main functionality,  all the time is just wasted in pushing their data into mongo which I have miserably failed.  can you help me with it.  **its really important project**

Comment: I would recommend creating a separate question with all the details as what is your use case, expected input and output and I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Veeram I tried it, writing but I wasn't able to frame my problem exactly its too big to write and explain I have already tried,

Comment: @Veeram hey last question man : in the above document can I directly find the car (object inside array) as it also has `_id` that means it is also indexed by mongo so I should be able to access it by the `findById()` method,  if it is possible how can I find one specific car given I have its id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179418/discussion-between-user6202188-and-veeram).

Comment: This will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) you

Answer (score 0):

First, assign the query to the variable...
then count cars array... like below

```
var obj = db.company.find(_id:"5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9").toArray();

var count = obj[0].cars.length
```

If you will find by _id obj[index] always will be 0.

Comment: get("/car/{id}", (req, res) => { // ? detail of specific car *how can I* query the above collection to find the given car in the `cars` array present in each document, I think we should be able to find it fast as it has `_id` with it so it means mongo would have index it

Comment: app.get("/car/:id", (req, res)=>{ var car = req.params.id    db.collection.find(_id: car)})

Comment: `let car_id = req.params.id;

        CompanyModel.find({
                _id: car_id
        }, (err, car) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.statusMessage = "Error : while getting specific car";
                    res.status(400).end();
                    return;
                }
                res.status(200);
                res.send(car);
        });`             **what you have told gives the companies and not the cars  plz see this : https://pastebin.com/ZxW525yB**

Comment: @user6202188 I think you can use the same answer of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178881/mongo-query-getting-a-specific-object-its-id-is-known-from-array-of-objec/52179116#52179116

Comment: @AnouarKacem the problem is its is not sure I don't know the company _id, **https://pastebin.com/ZxW525yB** all the separate objects specify one company, and each of them have cars --> list of car

Comment: db.data.find({"cars._id": '5b8ef8b7d1a7c2156417de72'},{"cars.$.model":1}).toArray() - returns One car - tested on mongo shell and MongoDB Compass